# How to set the path to the log report with FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to set the path to the log report with FFmpeg with a command like:

```bsh
ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel repeat+info -report file=ffreport.log -i <link>.m3u8 ...
```

The file specified is actually being ignored. How to solve this?
*Use ENV vars is not possible.*

Also, how to make the report not overwrite the previous report (if there is one)?

Actually I just used the %t in the name of the report and now the file is not overwritten but it creates other reports. My goal is to append the new data to the previous report generated.

Comment: Why is use ENV vars is not possible?

Comment: I thought it was not possible because the process is started and controlled from Node.js with a spawn command. Actually reading the docs I've found that the third parameter can be used to set env variables. Now I'm using it this way but my personal choice would be to set it with the other flags.

Comment: This link is related to the second question, maybe something has been done in the last 7 years: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/3059.

Comment: Meanwhile this questions doesn't get answered I'll try it with a Node.js script

Comment: I have changed the priority from wish to "normal" in: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/3059 because this is a must-have feature.